# Showing MySql error in tickets

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, syntax-error

I have a problem on my website.

When I want to reply a ticket if I use somewhere the the symbol ' it shows:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '''', now())' at line 2

Is there a way to edit something on the PHP form of the "ticket reply" so I could type words like "it's" and words with the ' symbol.

Comment: @Fred-ii- how could you know?

Comment: @AlanMachado let's call it *"experience"*, oh... and the *"so I could type words like "it's" and words with the `'` symbol."* ;-)